# netserverenum's return

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

*Hello,* I am using **NetServerEnum** to get a list of local networking computer (LAN)
I'd like to know its return (out) addresses
For example, should they be something like

- \192.168.1.10\ComputerName1
- \192.168.1.10\ComputerName2
- \192.168.1.10\ComputerName3

? Or just the computer names existing on the networking router ?

I am not on a networking machine to test it, it'll be really kind of you to inform me this.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

NetServerEnum is basically a leftover from the NetBIOS days, so it only deals in "flat" (NetBIOS) names. Here's a bit of code to show what names it can give you though:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 

    SERVER_INFO_100 *info;
    DWORD count;
    DWORD total_servers;
    DWORD resume = 0;

    NetServerEnum(NULL, 
        100, 
        (BYTE **)&info, 
        MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
        &count, 
        &total_servers, 
        SV_TYPE_NT, NULL, 
        &resume);

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        std::wcout << info[i].sv100_name << "\n";

    NetApiBufferFree(info);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name or IP-address of network router is not returned. Only computer name is returned in **sv100_name** or **sv101_name** field of SERVER_INFO_10x structure as:

- ComputerName0
- ComputerName1
- ComputerName2
- ...
- ComputerNameN